# Odd behavior when using "lodsb" and "inc %si"

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to increment the `%si` register by 1 in x86, however I'm having some odd behavior. Note: I'm running this in a loop.

This increments `%si` by two during every loop iteration:

```
loop:   inc %si
        lodsb
        jmp loop
```

And this increments `%si` by one for every iteration:

```
         mov %si, %cx
loop:    lodsb
         inc %cx
         mov %cx, %si
         jmp loop
```

Is my assumption correct? And is this the correct way to do this?

This is an example using BIOS interrupts that works:

```
bios_write:
        push %bp
        mov %sp, %bp
        pusha
        mov 4(%bp), %cx
0:      mov %cx, %si
        lodsb
        cmp $0, %al
        je 1f
        push %ax
        call bios_putchar
        pop %ax
        inc %cx
        jmp 0b
1:      popa
        mov %bp, %sp
        pop %bp
        ret
```

And this is an example that doesn't:

```
bios_write:
        push %bp
        mov %sp, %bp
        pusha
        mov 4(%bp), %si
0:      lodsb
        cmp $0, %al
        je 1f
        push %ax
        call bios_putchar
        pop %ax
        inc %si
        jmp 0b
1:      popa
        mov %bp, %sp
        pop %bp
        ret
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `lods` instruction increments si/esi/rsi by the operand size. (So, for example, `lodsb` increments si/esi/rsi by 1 and `lodsw` increments si/esi/rsi by 2.)

Thus, in your loop using the `lodsb` instruction, there should not also be an instruction to increment `si`.